# value range in negative and positive range until 0 with ternary operations?

Tags: javascript, optimization, coding-style, ternary-operator

I got an problem i'd like to solve.
This expression works as long as x is positive

```
x > 0 ? x - y : x + y;
```

When it gets negative however this is where the problem begins.
So i thought of

```
x !=0 & x < 0 ? x - y : Math.abs(x - y)*-1)
```

but this gets me nowhere and i solved it by:

```
if (x > 0 && x - y > 0) {
    x -= y;
} else if (x < 0 && x + y > 0) {
    x += y;
} else {
    x = 0;
}
```

this however is long and appears not elegant. 
any way to make this shorter and efficient with ternary operations?

Comment: What about the first statement doesn't work? It's not clear what is broken so we can't really help you come up with something more elegant.

Comment: You lose a lot of readability, but `x += (x > 0 && x > y) ? -y : (x < 0 && (x + y) > 0 ? y : 0);`

Comment: Your second ternery expression uses `&` instead of `&&` - is this a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = x >=0 ? x - y : x + y;
x = x < 0 ? 0 : x;
```

or

```
x = Math.max(x >= 0 ? x - y : x + y, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain your expression a bit with simple words? I don't really understand it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If x is positive, find x - y.  If x is negative, find x + y.  If the result of either of these operations is negative, return 0.

Comment: Thank you. This explains a lot!

Comment: Note that this doesn't do the same as your current code, so it won't work the same for all values.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
x = !x? 0 : Math.max(0, x-y*(Math.abs(x)/x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write the same using the conditional (aka ternary) operator:

```
x =
  x > 0 && x - y > 0 ? x - y :
  x < 0 && x + y > 0 ? x + y :
  0;
```

Or make the zero check separate:

```
x =
  x > 0 ? x - y :
  x < 0 ? x + y :
  0;
x = x > 0 ? x : 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Guffa. I didn't realise that I can "nest" an expression the way you did. Good thing to learn and it explains a lot of code I previously don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why you are trying to do what you are doing, but can't you simply do:

```
Math.max(x < 0 && x + y > 0 ? x + y : x - y, 0)
```

which seems to do the same thing as your if statement.

Comment: Thanks David, but i'm a newbie and I don't quite understand your expression. Could please explain it a bit? I'll be really thankfull.

Comment: What I am saying is: If the second part of your if statement is relevant ( 'x < 0 && x + y > 0 ?' ) then x+y  ( 'x + y' ) otherwhise 'x-y' (always the first part) however when it's negative it should be set to 0 according to your last if statement for which the Math.max is. This is essentially the same as mVChr wrote later in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers all solve your problem, but illustrate what I think is a major problem with ternary expressions -- they often result in code that is hard to understand.  That is why I rarely use them.

I think the code you wrote with the if/else statements is by far the best solution. I have been programming for over 40 years, and, believe me, you should always favor writing code that is easy to understand over code that is supposedly "elegant". It will save you lots of time, particularly when you go back to the code after a long period of time and forget what you were trying to do.

Comment: Holly words, however many code snippets I try to understand are using syntax that means nothing to me including ternary operators and expressions that I simply don't understand. I covered a lot of books and doc's and there is nothing about more complex conditionals, arrays etc. I got problems after not seeing code for couple of days ;-)